# C# how to make a pin code, that only unlocks something when typed in the right order

Tags: c#

I am making a vault application that requires a code to be entered in a specific order (1 2 3)
Now I have made that the vault will unlock when 1 2 and 3 are pressed, but the order doesn't matter at all.
I want to make that the vault ONLY unlocks when the button 1 is pressed first, 2 second and 3 thirth.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you accepting/reading the input?  Do you have any code to share?  If you are taking the input and building it as a single string a simple solution is `input == answer` as then it has to match exactly.

Comment: Put both the right combination (correct PIN) and the input combination into an `IEnumerable<T>` (for example a `List<int>` or `List<char>`) and check if they are [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348567.aspx).

Comment: I hope this is for a game or something that doesn't need to be secure. Otherwise, I suggest you take a course on cryptography or have it built by someone who understands cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

You might be overthinking this.

```
public bool VaultLock(string key)
{
    if(key == "1234")
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the numbers to a string and then match the string to the correct PIN.

```
private static string THECORRECTPIN = "1234";
private string _PinEntered{get;set;}
public void KeyPressed(string number)
{
    _PinEntered += number;//here's the important bit
    if(_PinEntered == THECORRECTPIN)
    {
        Unlock();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you please give a small demonstration of your idea? Im kind of a newbie..

Answer (score 0):

Make a statemachine that accepts an input (one letter) causing it to move to another state. 2.

States can be valid (all the input is valid), invalid (more input is needed) or error (valid state can never be reached again).

Give it five states:
1. Start, no input has been given, with a transition on input 1 to state 2.
2. Has a transition on input 2 to state 3.
3. Has a transition on input 3 to state 4.
4. Is a valid state, has no transitions
5. Error state, no transitions.

If an input is given that the current state has no stransitions for go to the error state.

Update, this concept can get very complicated, it forms the basics for search engines. This implementation is extremely basic:

```
namespace Algorithms
{
    public class Automaat
    {
        public const char Epsilon = default(char);
        private Graph current, valid;

        public Automaat(string text)
        {
            Graph start = new Graph();
            valid = new Graph();

            current = start;

            foreach (var letter in text)
            {
                var next = new Graph();
                current.SetTransition(next, letter);
                current = next;
            }

            valid = current;
            current = start;
        }

        public void Input(char symbol)
        {
            if (current != null)
                current = current.Next(symbol);
        }

        public bool IsValid()
        {
            return current == valid;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Holds connections to other graphs, the position of that graph in the array relative to the alphabet determines what symbol that link uses.
        /// </summary>
        private class Graph
        {
            private static char[] alphabet;
            Graph[] nodes;

            public Graph()
            {
                nodes = new Graph[26];
            }

            public void SetTransition(Graph graph, char symbol)
            {
                nodes[ConvertToIndex(symbol)] = graph;
            }

            public Graph Next(char symbol)
            {
                return nodes[ConvertToIndex(symbol)];
            }

            private int ConvertToIndex(char symbol)
            {
                return symbol - 'a';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you please give a small demonstration of your idea? Im kind of a newbie..